# Difficulty converting a 5-star rating scale to 'Positive' and 'Negative' Scale in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv that contains integers on a scale of 1-5.  I am trying to write a new csv that takes any 1's and 2's in the original csv and returns 'negative' and then all 3's, 4's and 5's returned as 'positive'.  Here is what I have so far (I am using Pandas & TextBlob FYI):

```
ratings = pd.read_csv(r'/Users/jackcarlson/Downloads/amazon-cell-phones-reviews/only_rating.csv')

sentimentals = []
sentlist = [1,2]

for i in ratings.itertuples():
    if i in sentlist:
            neg = True
    if neg:
        sentimentals.append("negative")
    else:
        sentimentals.append("positive")
print(sentimentals)

with open('/Users/jackcarlson/Downloads/starreview.txt', 'w') as filehandle:
    for listitem in sentimentals:
        filehandle.write('%s\n' % listitem)
```

Here is what my csv looks like:

[image]

My for loop is returning only 'negative' for each line.  I'm sure this is a simple mistake (I am very new to Python) and any help would be amazing.  Thank you!

Comment: Replace `if neg:` with `if i in sentlist:` and remove the lines `if i in sentlist: neg = True` from above it. Should work.

Comment: @OD1995  Thank you for your response.  When I make that change it returns only 'positive' now.

Comment: Maybe it's worth updating your question to give a better idea of the format of `ratings`? Namely, what columns does it have and perhaps some example rows

Comment: Like @OD1995 was saying, it appears to be an issue with the neg = True part. Once this value is set to True, it will remain true for the duration of the for loop as you have not set any way for it to change back to False.  You could fix this by adding neg = False inside the for loop (before the first if statement)

Comment: It is quite strange that a tuple has  value 0 or 1.  Maybe you should extract the value of the 'rating' before comparing it .

Comment: Could you use a debugger to figure out what path it's taking? Perhaps set a breakpoint on "if i in sentlist", look at each i, and then step through each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to loop through the rows as tuples if there's just one column. Instead, loop through just that column:

```
for i in ratings['rating']:
    if i in sentlist:
        sentimentals.append("negative")
    else:
        sentimentals.append("positive")
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work.

```
for i in ratings.itertuples():
    if i in sentlist:
        sentimentals.append("negative")
    else:
        sentimentals.append("positive")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can do with with `pandas` using the [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) methods:

```
d = {1: 'negative',
     2: 'negative',
     3: 'positive',
     4: 'positive',
     5: 'postive'}

ratings = pd.read_csv(r'/Users/jackcarlson/Downloads/amazon-cell-phones-reviews/only_rating.csv')

(ratings['rating'].map(d)
 .to_csv('/Users/jackcarlson/Downloads/starreview.txt',
         index=False, header=False))
```

---

An alternative, using [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead of looping to create `"sentimentals"`:

```
sentimentals = ['negative' if x <= 2 else 'positive' for x in ratings['rating']]
```